# How to show border only value existing row in PaginatedDataTable2

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've created flutter with PaginatedDataTable2 as below source code

```
Expanded(
    child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            cardColor: backgroundEndColor, dividerColor: Colors.white),
        child: PaginatedDataTable2(
          controller: paginatorController,
          hidePaginator: true,
          headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
            (states) {
              return Colors.white;
            },
          ),
          source: dataTable,
          header: const ListHeader(),
          columns: tableColumns,
          columnSpacing: 0,
          horizontalMargin: 10,
          rowsPerPage: projectPartProgressController.rowsPerPage.value,
          showCheckboxColumn: false,
        )),
  )
```

But the last page result is showing with horizontal border that no value inside as below

[image]

Is there any way to remove the border for those no value row?

Comment: Try with `renderEmptyRowsInTheEnd: false`. The description says `Flag to render empty(invisible) rows in the end of the table when there is a fixed number of [rowsPerPage] and the number of visible rows is smaller This value defaults to true`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find 'renderEmptyRowsInTheEnd' in PaginatedDataTable2 Widget where is it?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2 If you use this package then there should be that property. Make sure you use the latest version.

Comment: After test with data_table_2: ^2.3.10 this property is able to use now thank you so much